# decompression in c#

Tags: vb.net, compression

i have compressed an xml file and converted it into base64 format in web page.then i have passed the base64 string to windows application and converted it to unbase64 format.now i want to decompress this string in windows form only.
i have done the following in windows

```
dim decoded as byte()
decoded=convert.frombase64string(strreturndata)  // strreturndata is base64 string
dim decoders as string
decoders = encoding.utf8.getstring(decoded)
```

now i want to decompress this string using gzip stream class in windows form

Comment: is this C#?? sure looks like VB..

Comment: One always gets more answers in C#, hence the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get back the Base64 string, use this.

Try this:

```
byte[] x = Convert.FromBase64String(decodedString);
string mytext = System.Encoding.utf8.getstring(x, 0, x.length)
```

If you need to do more compression, you can use [Gzip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) compression and decompression or [DeflateStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) class.